# Language pgfgantt -> Translate to portuguese

Tags: pgfgantt, gantt

How to translate the text in Portuguese?
-Complete to completo
-Today to hoje

```
    \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\title{Gantt Charts with the pgfgantt Package}
\begin{document}

%
% A fairly complicated example from section 2.9 of the package
% documentation. This reproduces an example from Wikipedia:
% http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart
%
\definecolor{barblue}{RGB}{153,204,254}
\definecolor{groupblue}{RGB}{51,102,254}
\definecolor{linkred}{RGB}{165,0,33}
\renewcommand\sfdefault{phv}
\renewcommand\mddefault{mc}
\renewcommand\bfdefault{bc}
\setganttlinklabel{s-s}{Disciplina cursada UTFPR - 1S2019}
\setganttlinklabel{f-s}{Início 2021}
\setganttlinklabel{f-s}{Ingresso ao Programa de Pós Graduação UNIFESP - 2S2021}
\setganttlinklabel{f-f}{Finalização}
\sffamily
\begin{ganttchart}[
    canvas/.append style={fill=none, draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
    hgrid style/.style={draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
    vgrid={*1{draw=black!5, line width=.75pt}},
    today=12,
    today rule/.style={
      draw=black!64,
      dash pattern=on 3.5pt off 4.5pt,
      line width=1.5pt
    },
    today label font=\small\bfseries,
    title/.style={draw=none, fill=none},
    title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
    title label node/.append style={below=7pt},
    include title in canvas=false,
    bar label font=\mdseries\small\color{black!70},
    bar label node/.append style={left=2cm},
    bar/.append style={draw=none, fill=black!63},
    bar incomplete/.append style={fill=barblue},
    bar progress label font=\mdseries\footnotesize\color{black!70},
    group incomplete/.append style={fill=groupblue},
    group left shift=0,
    group right shift=0,
    group height=.5,
    group peaks tip position=0,
    group label node/.append style={left=.6cm},
    group progress label font=\bfseries\small,
    link/.style={-latex, line width=1.5pt, linkred},
    link label font=\scriptsize\bfseries,
    link label node/.append style={below left=-2pt and 0pt}
  ]{1}{13}
  \gantttitle[
    title label node/.append style={below left=7pt and -3pt}
  ]{Meses:\quad1}{1}
  \gantttitlelist{2,...,24}{1} \\
  \ganttgroup[progress=57]{Programa de Pós-Graduação em Engenharia Química}{1}{24} \\
  \ganttbar[
    progress=100,
    name=WBS1A
  ]{\textbf{Disciplina} TERMODINÂMICA DA ENGENHARIA QUÍMICA}{1}{1} \\
  \ganttbar[
    progress=100,
    name=WBS1B
  ]{\textbf{Disciplina} ENGENHARIA DE POLÍMEROS}{1}{7} \\
  \ganttbar[
    progress=100,
    name=WBS1C
  ]{\textbf{Disciplina} CINÉTICA APLICADA E REATORES QUÍMICOS}{8}{12} \\
  \ganttbar[
    progress=100,
    name=WBS1D
  ]{\textbf{Disciplina} METODOLOGIA CIENTÍFICA}{8}{12} \\ 
    \ganttbar[
    progress=100,
    name=WBS1E
  ]{\textbf{Disciplina} PROCESSOS DE SEPARAÇÃO COM MEMBRANAS}{8}{12} \\
  
  \ganttbar[
    progress=0,
    name=WBS1F
  ]{\textbf{Disciplina} SEMINÁRIOS EM ENGENHARIA QUÍMICA}{14}{18}
  
  \\[grid]
   \ganttbar[progress=65]{\textbf{Dissertação} Revisão Bibliográfica}{1}{16} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=0]{\textbf{Dissertação} Activity F}{6}{8} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=0]{\textbf{Dissertação} Activity G}{9}{10}
  \ganttlink[link type=s-s]{WBS1A}{WBS1B}
  \ganttlink[link type=f-s]{WBS1B}{WBS1C}
  \ganttlink[
    link type=f-f,
    link label node/.append style=left
  ]{WBS1C}{WBS1D}
\end{ganttchart}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Quick comment. Checking page 35 [pgfgannt](https://ctan.dcc.uchile.cl/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfgantt/pgfgantt.pdf) on CTAN. You may add `progress label text = {Completo}` on `\ganttbar`options inside `[]`. I will check for the label "today" and how to do the changes properly. Portuguese: Saudações do Brasil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the [pgfgantt on CTAN](https://ctan.dcc.uchile.cl/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfgantt/pgfgantt.pdf):

- Page 11: /pgfgantt/today label = `<text>`
- Page 35: /pgfgantt/progress label text = `<text>`

  - `\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0, verbatim]{#1}\% complete`

Based on these infos, insert inside the options of `\begin{ganttchart}[` the following commands

```
progress label text = {#1\% Completo},
today label = {Hoje}
```

In your file, it may be done at the end. Sorry, I will not copy all the file here.

[image]

The following picture shows the results. The words "Completo" are added after the percentage number ("`#1\%`" was necessary to do it), and "Hoje" appears at the end.

[image]

Bonus round: pgfgantt has similar sintaxes to the [tcolorbox](https://ctan.dcc.uchile.cl/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) package. When you understand one, the other is a natural extension.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding the comment: there are options `today label` and `progress label text`. Page 11 (today label) and page 35 (progress label) of the [pgfgantt manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfgantt/pgfgantt.pdf).

Code:

```
\begin{ganttchart}[
    canvas/.append style={fill=none, draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
    hgrid style/.style={draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
    vgrid={*1{draw=black!5, line width=.75pt}},
    today=12,
    today rule/.style={
      draw=black!64,
      dash pattern=on 3.5pt off 4.5pt,
      line width=1.5pt
    },
    today label=hoje,
    progress label text={%
    \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0, verbatim]{#1}\% completo%
    },
    today label font=\small\bfseries,
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: And we post our answers almost at the same :).